# Sort JSON object by data key from highest to lowest - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to sort the following json -

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBJgt.png

I want it to sort it by "assists" which is one of the data keys inside "elements" and so it displays them from highest to lowest.
Anyone know how this could be done?

The code below is the public api im fetching

```
var request2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
request2.open("GET", "https://cors- 
anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/bootstrap-static/", true);
request2.onload = function () {
var data2 = JSON.parse(this.response);
console.log(data2);
}
request2.send();
```

Comment: Do you want to sort the elements array by assists?

Comment: Yes. I am not sure how to attempt this

Comment: Is this an object, or are you dealing with a stream of text in JSON format?

Comment: an object fetched from a public api.

Comment: To sort an array you normally use `Array#sort`. Have you tried that?

Comment: A screenshot of something that is essentially text (JSON) is not very useful. Please provide sample data -- possibly reduced/simplified -- as test inside your question (you can format it with the `<>` button).

Comment: `const data = { elements: [ { assists: 3 }, { assists: 2 }, { assists: 1 } ] }; data.elements.sort(({assists: a}, {assists: b}) => a - b)`

Comment: I have provided the code I am using to fetch the public api and log it to the console.